# Tell zstdcat to decompress only the first N bytes of a file

Tags: zstd

I have a collection of files compressed with zstandard, and would like to look at the first 10 megabytes of the files without decompressing the entire file. Is there way to get zstdcat to only decompress the first N bytes of a file, rather than the entire file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zstdcat SRC_FILE | head -c BYTES > DEST_FILE`